# Is it possible to cancel an Angular 4 lifecycle hook?

Tags: angular

I'm currently using the ngDoCheck() lifecycle hook and it is fired alot of times. There is a certain situation when I do no longer need this lifecycle hook.

So my question is: Can I cancel this lifecycle hook?

Comment: have you tried using a boolean variable to see if you need to run the code within or not?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon That's what I'm currently doing. However I was just wondering if cancellation was possible because that performs better than checking a boolean variable multiple times each second.

Answer (score 3):

No, lifecycle hooks can not be canceled.

If you don't need it anymore, just return without executing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You shold implement something like this:

```
   ngDoCheck() {
      if (this.items.length !== this.prevLength) {
         // and here do what you want
      }
```